# Does ServiceStack support reverse routing?

Tags: c#, routes, servicestack, reverse

Following REST it is advisable that API is discoverable and should be interlinked.

Does ServiceStack support any kind of reverse routing? I'm looking for something like `Url.RouteLink` in ASP MVC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some mixed concepts stated here.

1. In and effort of trying to comply with REST you wish to embed URI's in your responses.
2. How best to achieve embedding URI's in your responses. You've assumed a "Reverse Routing" mechanism is how this should be done.

#### REST style vs Strong-typing

I want to be explicitly mention here that one doesn't imply the other. On the one hand you're looking to follow a REST architecture (with whatever system you're building) and on the other you wish to follow strong-typing practices of using a typed-API, in this case to generate the external URI's of your API. These are somewhat contrasting styles as REST doesn't promote typed-APIs preferring to instead bind to the external URI surface of your APIs and loosely-typed Content-Types. Whilst a strong-typed language would recommend binding to a typed API, e.g. like the [end-to-end typed API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) ServiceStack supports out-of-the-box.

#### Generating strong-typed URI's in ServiceStack

There's no ASP.NET MVC "Reverse Routing" concept/functionality in ServiceStack explicitly, but you can re-use the same functionality that the [.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) uses to generate and use user-defined Custom routes. To use this, you need to specify your custom routes on the DTO's (i.e. with the `[Route]` attribute as opposed to the fluent API in AppHost), e.g:

```
[Route("/reqstars/search", "GET")]
[Route("/reqstars/aged/{Age}")]
public class SearchReqstars : IReturn<ReqstarsResponse>
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}

var relativeUrl = new SearchReqstars { Age = 20 }.ToUrl("GET");
var absoluteUrl = EndpointHost.Config.WebHostUrl.CombineWith(relativeUrl);

relativeUrl.Print(); //=  /reqstars/aged/20
absoluteUrl.Print(); //=  http://www.myhost.com/reqstars/aged/20
```

Or if you just want the Absolute Url you can use the `ToAbsoluteUri` Extension method:

```
var absoluteUrl = new SearchReqstars { Age = 20 }.ToAbsoluteUri();
```

Comment: Thanks for the ToUrl() method. You are completely right in your 2. point. But I'm litte confused. So you don't recommend that I embed Uris into my Response DTOs? I just want to make sure that client doesn't have to hardcode URIs.

Comment: IMO you should only be embedding URI's in your responses when there's a clear advantage of doing so. I would analyze the burden on the clients between using URI's vs a typed-API to help determining this for you. To remain value-focused I only adopt practices of which I know what the advantages are (so I can maximize it's effectiveness). There are times when embedded URI's provide value (i.e. hot-linking documents), but a pure REST/HATEOS/HAL system is very different beast to building a quasi-REST service - [which I don't believe provides value](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=665).

Comment: Interesting stand point. So the alternative would be to just to document the URIs.

Comment: Right, you can document your API. The auto-generated `/metadata` pages largely does this automatically for you and you can further annotate your DTO's with `[Api]` and `[ApiMember]` to provide further content on the relevant metadata pages. The other option is to provide native language bindings with a typed API (SS supports this with C#/.NET Service Clients) so consumers don't have to manually parse response types, construct URLs or worry about HTTP + Serialization libs to use to call your services. IMO Native SDK's provides most value/least burden for end-users.